# filter a datatable to contain unique columns

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a datatable as follows

```
ID(INT NOT NULL AND PK)    Name(NOT NULL NVARCHAR)
1                          Apple
2                          Apple
3                          Apple
4                          Orange
5                          Apple
6                          Orange
```

I need to filter the datatable such that it contains only unique Names. ID can be any one of the row selected in Table

Required Datatable

```
ID(INT NOT NULL AND PK)    Name(NOT NULL NVARCHAR)
1/2/3/5(any one)           Apple
4/6(any one)               Orange
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use LINQ to DataTable with `GroupBy` method:

```
var result = dt.AsEmumerable()
               .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Name"))
               .Select(g => g.First())
               .CopyToDataTable();
```